# How to call other functions while update image(opencv) on a label Pyqt5?

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I want to update the label with images but when I start to update the label, nothing works until the updating is done for example I want to pause updating or closing the window. It worked perfect when I used tkinter but it doesn't work same method in Pyqt5. Here is the code I have

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QDialog, QMainWindow,QMessageBox,QGroupBox,QSlider,QPushButton,QRadioButton,QLabel,QCheckBox,QFrame,QWidget,QTabWidget,QProgressBar,QTextBrowser,QTableWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QSize,QThread, QRect,QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont,QPixmap,QIcon
import cv2
import os
import glob



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(800, 800)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(165, 125, 61, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(Form)
        self.image_frame = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QRect(350, 200, 111, 31))
        
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.load_images_from_folder)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.btn1.setText(_translate("Form","Btn"))
        

    def load_images_from_folder(self):
        for filename in glob.glob('path/*.jpg'):
            img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            img = cv2.resize(img,(200,200))
            print(filename)
            self.showimg(img)

    def showimg(self,img):
        self.image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.image = QtGui.QImage(self.image.data, self.image.shape[1], self.image.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
        self.image_frame.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
        self.image_frame.setGeometry(QRect(70, 310, 461, 441))
        Form.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After I clicked Btn label updates but I can't click Btn again until the updating is finished

Comment: Hi, I am not a Pyqt5, but until a good answer appears, did you try to execute it in another thread ? Its common to use events / threads in other programming languages and let the thread where the UI is run in the main thread.

Comment: Built-in Python libraries such as `threading` and `asyncio` will help since you're trying to make the process asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UI environments, control has to be returned as quickly as possible to the main thread. If you have lots of image processing, this means that the function that loads the image (which also calls the function that *sets* the image) will not release control to the main thread until it's finished.

If you don't, the result is that the UI will be completely frozen (no updates, no user input) until that function returns.

The solution is to use threads, but you also need to consider that UI elements are involved, and **no access** is allowed to UI elements from external threads. So, the *actual* solution is to use *QThreads* and custom signals: Qt signals are thread safe, and they are queued whenever two objects belonging to different threads are trying to communicate.

In this specific case, the thread will be a QThread with a custom signal (which has to be emitted whenever a new image is ready):

```
class ImageLoader(QtCore.QThread):
    imageReady = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.images = []

    def run(self):
        while True:
            while self.images:
                img = cv2.imread(self.images.pop(), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
                img = cv2.resize(img,(200,200))
                self.imageReady.emit(img)

    def loadImages(self, imageList):
        # if you want to *clear* the current queue
        self.images[:] = imageList
        # otherwise, just append:
        # self.images.extend(imageList)
```

The implementation then requires to create the thread instance and add the images to the queue in `load_images_from_folder`:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        # ...
        self.imageLoader = ImageLoader()
        self.imageLoader.imageReady.connect(self.showimg)
        self.imageLoader.start()

    def load_images_from_folder(self):
        self.imageLoader.loadImages(glob.glob('path/*.jpg'))
```

Important notes:

1. editing files generated with `pyuic` is considered **bad** practice, as it almost always leads to unexpected behavior and bugs that are difficult to track; the comment in the header of those files is pretty clear: you should **not** edit them; instead, create those files, *leave them as they are*, and then import them in your main script, as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html);
2. accessing `Form` (`Form.update()`), which is fundamentally a *global* variable, is another bad practice; just like editing pyuic files, it's something that should **never** be done unless you *really* know what you're doing (and if you do know, you won't probably do it at all); in any case, setting the pixmap on a label automatically schedules an update, so that function call is completely useless since we're properly using threading, which allows the main event loop to request updates on the UI;
3. setting fixed geometries is *yet* another practice usually discouraged; learn how to use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and how to [use them in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) instead; if you want the QLabel to have a fixed size, use `setFixedSize()`;

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right about layout managers which is better when I use  different OS. One more question how could I pause and resume to show images with another button?